# How to wp_add_inline_script when there's no registered script to hook onto?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

The docs for `wp_add_inline_script` state that it:

> Adds extra code to a registered script.

How do you do it when there is no registered script?  In my case, my only registered JS is before the closing `body` tag, and I want an inline script (js detection) in the head.  Specifically I want my inline JS to come before my styles, but after the `<title>` and `<meta>` tags.

I tried to enqueue an empty script and then use it to hook my inline script onto, but that didn't work.  Like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-js-detection', null, array(), null, false);

wp_add_inline_script( 'theme-js-detection', 
    '(function(H){H.className=H.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,"js")})(document.documentElement)' 
);
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To place your script before the styles I would use the action hook [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)  with high priority:

```
function my_special_inline_script() {
    ?>
    <script>
        // your JS code
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_special_inline_script', 1, 1 );
```

`<title>` and `<meta>` should be before this as long [`wp_head()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) is placed directly before the closing `<head>` tag as recommended.

Comment: Note: For the WP admin backend, you also have to add this function to the `admin_enqueue_scripts` action.